# I don't receive email from php mailer

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP and have only been using css/html. I have checked the email/spam etc and just wanted to see if you guys could notice any major problems with the script.

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$youremail = 'stackoverflow@gmail.com';
$fromsubject = 'stackoverflow@domain.com';
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$message = $_POST['message']; 
    $to = $youremail; 
    $mailsubject = 'Masage recived from'.$fromsubject.' Contact Page';
    $body = $fromsubject.'

    The person that contacted you is  '.$fname.' '.$lname.'
     E-mail: '.$mail.'

     Message: 
     '.$message.'

     |---------END MESSAGE----------|'; 
echo "Thank you fo your feedback. I will contact you shortly if needed.<br/>Go to <a    href='/index.html'>Home</a>"; 
                            mail($to, $subject, $body);
 } else { 
echo "You must write a message. </br> Please go to <a href='/contact.php'>Contact     Page</a>"; 
}
?>
```

Note: it executes the code, I just don't receive the email

Comment: Is this on your local machine?

Comment: No, it's hosted on a server.

Comment: What errors are you getting for your mail server?  Also, have you set your From header?

Comment: No errors, it goes to "Thank you fo your feedback" but no email received.
I'm not quite sure what you mean by setting the form header.

Comment: I don't mean on the page you send the mail from, but your actual mail log, where it logs the actual send action of the mail.  As to the **From** header, that's required.  Did you read the mail() php manual page?

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

Read the docs carefully and thoroughly, it describes quite a few things that can go wrong.

But most importantly: go through the logs of the MTA you're using! That's where you're going to find what happened to the message(s).

Answer (score 0):

the mail() function in php requires you to define several parameters in php.ini
http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

depending on your setup you'll either want to define a 3rd party SMTP server or move the mail to a directory. There are also php frameworks dedicated to email such as http://laravel.com/docs/mail